# limitTo and Filter in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to get one result from an array in `ng-bind` using `filter`. I want to do as below

```
<h1 ng-bind="item.Description as item in Items | filter: {id: someID}"></h1>
```

I want to set `h1` to `item.Description` from `Items` where `someID` comes from a drop down. That means, when I select from drop down, `h1` is set by filtering `Items` by `SomeID`. It's like `h1 = Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == someID).Description`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `ng-bind` wouldn't recoginize the `item in items` syntax. But as you mentioned in the title, you can utilize `limitTo` with `ng-repeat` to achieve more or less same result. Like this:

```
<h1 ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {id: someId} | limitTo: 1">
    {{item.Description}}
</h1>
```

[**working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/FdR6NhWAgUGBB6OtoiH1?p=preview) (used number input for `someId` for simplicity)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dropdown then you know what the selection is (via the ng-model). The code you have is using ng-bind but it's the text for ng-repeat. Your best bet is to have a method on the controller:

```
getItemDescription() {
  const selection = this.form.dropdown.selection; // Holds the dropdown 'selection' object (from the ng-model on your select dropdown);
  return Items.find((item) => item === selection).description;
}
```

Then your HTML becomes:

```
<h1 ng-bind="vm.getItemDescription()"></h1>
```